# Xorg using 20-60% CPU

Tags: xorg, log, cpu-load, xorg.conf

My PC was running just fine last night. I didnt make any system changes. As far as I can remember the only change I made was my desktop background and now my CPU is running so slow it's near unusable. Here is what my xorg log looks like. Im a noob so I dont know what any of it means really. Can somebody help? I am booted from a LIVE USB atm and it is running just fine.

```
[    35.381] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
[    35.381] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    35.381] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    35.381] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017 x86_64
[    35.381] Kernel command line: file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --- maybe-ubiquity
[    35.381] Build Date: 28 March 2017  06:16:52AM
[    35.381] xorg-server 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    35.381] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    35.381]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    35.381] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    35.381] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jun 22 19:29:45 2017
[    35.382] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    35.382] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    35.382] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    35.382] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    35.382] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    35.382] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    35.382] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    35.382] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    35.382] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    35.382] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    35.382] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    35.382] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    35.382]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.382] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    35.382]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.382] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    35.382]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.382] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    35.382]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.382] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    35.382]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    35.382] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    35.382] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    35.382] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    35.382] (II) Loader magic: 0x5568c57ad020
[    35.382] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    35.382]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    35.382]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    35.382]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    35.382]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    35.383] (++) using VT number 7

[    35.383] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    35.383] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    35.383] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    35.394] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1462:1113 rev 6, Mem @ 0xf7400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    35.394] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1391:1462:1113 rev 162, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    35.394] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    35.394] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    35.395] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.395]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.395]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    35.395] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.395] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.395] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.395] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    35.395] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    35.395] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.395] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    35.395] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    35.395] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    35.395] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    35.395] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.395] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.396] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    35.396] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.396]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.14
[    35.396]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.396]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.396] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.396] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    35.396] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.396]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.19.3
[    35.396]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.396]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.396] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.396] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.396] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.396]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[    35.396]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.396]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.396] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.396] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    35.396] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.396]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[    35.396]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.396]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.396] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    35.396] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    35.396] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    35.396] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    35.396] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    35.396] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    35.396] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    35.397] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    35.397] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    35.397] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    35.397] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    35.397] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.397] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    35.397] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.397]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.14
[    35.397]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.397]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.397] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    35.397] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    35.397] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.397] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.397] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    35.397] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.397]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.19.3
[    35.397]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.397]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.397] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    35.397] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    35.397] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.397] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.397] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.397] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.397]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[    35.397]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.397]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.397] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.397] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    35.397] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.397] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    35.397] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    35.397] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.397]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[    35.397]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    35.397]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    35.397] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.397] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.397] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    35.397] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Mar 7 18:44:43 2017 -0500
[    35.397] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    35.397]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    35.397]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    35.398]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    35.398]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    35.398]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    35.398]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    35.398]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    35.398]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    35.398]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    35.398]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    35.398]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    35.398]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    35.398]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    35.398] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    35.398] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    35.398] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    35.414] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
```

Sorry if I formatted that badly. Let me know what else I can change or include.

Adding the requested output; There was no output for the dpkg cmd, but here is what lspci -k ... gave me:

```
lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'` and `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` please? Looks like an issue with your nvidia graphics drivers.

Comment: @ByteCommander I edited the post to include the output you requested. Nothing came back from the dpkg... cmd though.

Comment: So you don't have a nvidia driver installed, but strangely it also doesn't show any kernel modules for the integrated Intel graphics at all. For now, I'd try installing some nvidia drivers, e.g. by running `sudo apt install nvidia-375` from a terminal (or TTY: press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to log in  to a pure full-screen terminal if the GUI takes too long to load) of your installation.

Comment: THANK YOU! @ByteCommander That did it. I dont see an option to mark that as the right answer though. BTW any idea why my wifi card is working now when it wasnt before? Also, why might this have happened in the first place? It can't be from changing my background can it?

Comment: Nice, but no idea about the cause. Your wifi issue would probably be worth another separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you don't have a nvidia driver installed, but strangely it also
>   doesn't show any kernel modules for the integrated Intel graphics at
>   all. For now, I'd try installing some nvidia drivers, e.g. by running
>   sudo apt install nvidia-375 from a terminal (or TTY: press Ctrl+Alt+F1
>   to log in to a pure full-screen terminal if the GUI takes too long to
>   load) of your installation.

– Byte Commander